# echo <a> tag, with or without rel="nofollow" depending on page, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to echo out an link to a **site A** in the footer of **site B**, so that it is more seo friendly and not flagged as a site wide link, and ignored / given less weight to, id like to set it to rel="nofollow", apart from on the home page.

Is there a simple way to do this in word press something like :

```
if ($page == 'homepage') {
        echo "<a href="#">Site A</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href="#" rel="nofollow">Site A</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) you need is `is_home()`:

```
if (is_home()) {
    echo "<a href='#'>Site A</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='#' rel='nofollow'>Site A</a>";
}
```

Comment: I ended up changing this to `$current_page = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
      $home_page = home_url()."/";

      if ( $current_page === $home_page ) {
          echo "<a href='#'>HOME</a>";
      } else {
          echo "<a href='#' rel='nofollow'>SUB PAGE</a>";
      }` Im not sure if its becuase im viewing the site locally so the url is `localhost:8888/site` so it thinks the site is a sub folder of localhost, but the above code works as a work around

Answer (score 1):

Try using the global Wordpress variable $pagename.

```
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
if ($pagename == 'homepage') {
        echo "<a href="#">Site A</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href="#" rel="nofollow">Site A</a>";
}
```